# How to set prunable layers for tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, pruning

I am applying the pruning function from `tensorflow_model_optimization`,    `tfmot.sparsity.keras.prune_low_magnitude()` to MobileNetV2.

Is there any way to set only some layers of the model to be prunable? For training, there is a method "`set_trainable`", but I haven't found any equivalent for pruning.

Any ideas or comments will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that you can also apply prune_low_magnitude() per layer.

So the workaround would be to define a list containing the names or types of the layers that shall be pruned, and iterate the layer-wise pruning over all layers in this list.

Comment: For anyone trying to do something similar, the docs for the same are available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/comprehensive_guide#prune_some_layers_sequential_and_functional)

Comment: Thanks for the link, this documentation was not available back then :)
It is very helpful, indeed!